# iOS:detect correct encoding of NSData

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsstring, nsdata, nsstringencoding

I hava a `NSData` object which represents a `NSString` object. I use `-[NSString initWithData:encoding:]` to get the string. Now the problem is how do I know the correct encoding type?

Thanks.

Edited:
I test and find: 
the supposing the `NSData` is encoding with A, and I try to use encoding B to create the `NSString`. Sometimes the string will be nil, but string can be not nil which is a messy code. So I can't get the correct string by testing the each encoding type.

Answer (score 0):

If the data came from a file, you can try `+[NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:usedEncoding:error:]`. But the method seems to try only a few encodings. The [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/) library supports more encodings.